# Program not starting from startup folder

Tags: windows-7, uac

I have a lot of Windows 7 PCs with a lot of users each and UAC enabled, some administrators but most standard users. I have made a program in C# which I want to start on startup for all users. I have put the exe file in the All users folder but it does not get lauched at startup, no matter what (even if an administrator logs in).
My application does not require admin rights and runs normally when double clicked by a standard user.
I have also tried with the "Run as administrator" checkbox checked in file properties but it still doesn't work.

Why is this happening and is there any way to make it work? I know about the task scheduler method, but I want to make it work by just putting the file in the startup folder. When some different file is put, for example notepad.exe, it runs. What makes my application different from notepad.exe? I have the code and can edit it if needed to make this work.

UPDATE:
Putting a shortcut to the file does not work.
Putting a batch file with "start myfile.exe" does not work.

Answer (score 1):

### There are two methods you can use to do this.

---

### The simple method:

1. Press <kbd>Windows Key</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
2. Paste "%programdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup" (WITH quotes)
3. Copy program shortcut to this folder

---

### The complex method:

1. Press <kbd>Windows Key</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
2. Type taskschd.msc
3. Select Task Scheduler Library" in the left pane, Click "New Folder..." under the actions and name it something like Custom Tasks (Name doesn't matter).
4. Select your new folder under "Task Scheduler Library" and click "Create Task..." under the actions pane.
5. Name it whatever you want.
6. Click Change User or Group, and type in "Users" (No quotes) and click OK.
7. Click the Triggers tab and click "New..."
8. Set "Begin the task:" to "At log on" and make sure it is set to "Any user".
9. Click OK.
10. Got to the Actions tab and click "New..."
11. Click "Browse" and find the file.
12. Add arguments if necessary.
13. Click OK
14. Click OK again.

---

Edit:
Sorry about the slow response. Outlook did not notify me about an RSS feed update.

Try creating a batch file without "start". Just do this:

```
@echo off
"FILEPATH"
```